# TLE in Fast Multiplication in spoj

Tags: java

How can I make this code faster?
Spoj said time limit exceeded when I paste this solution.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("the number of multiplications <= 1000: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    if (n <= 1000) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.print("First number to multiply");
    BigInteger l1 = new BigInteger(scanner.next());
    System.out.print("Second number to multiply");
    BigInteger l2 = new BigInteger(scanner.next());
if (l1.toString().length() == 10000 || l2.toString().length() == 10000) {
    System.err.println("numbers to multiply should be at most 10000 decimal digits each.");
    } else {
    System.out.println("Product: "+l1.multiply(l2));
    }
    }
    } else {
    System.err.println("number of multiplications should be less than or equal to 1000");
    }
    }
    }
```

update: I have now used a buffered reader but now I'm getting wrong answer even though my outputs are right. Here's my updated code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("the number of multiplications <= 1000: ");
int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
if (n <= 1000) {
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
System.out.print("First number to multiply: ");
BigInteger l1 = new BigInteger(reader.readLine());
System.out.print("Second number to multiply: ");
BigInteger l2 = new BigInteger(reader.readLine());
if (l1.toString().length() == 10000 || l2.toString().length() == 10000) {
System.err.println("numbers to multiply should be at most 10000 decimal digits each.");
} else {
System.out.println("Product: "+l1.multiply(l2));
}
}
    } else {
System.err.println("number of multiplications should be less than or equal to 1000");
}
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
System.err.println("invalid");
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The speed will always rely on how fast someone types into the System.in, no matter how many cycles you squeeze out of the statements.

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading input in java is very slow if you use Scanner. You can pass only problems with really small input using it. You should use `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` if you think the input can be larger. The rest of your algorithm is correct(although this problem is meant for testing own implementation of big integer numbers instead of built-in types).

EDIT: you are getting `WA` because of all the helper output you print to system.out. In programming competitions you should write nothing but the answer on the standard output. Thus you need to print only the result of the multiplication. Use the example. Your output should be precisely the same for your solution to pass.